How to speed up the following ELBO evaluation?
I have an estimation problem where I need to maximize the evidence lower bound:
$$ \mathrm{ELBO} = -\frac{1}{2} \Bigg( \mathbb{E}_{q(\theta)} \left[ \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})+ \log \left| \mathbf{C} \right| \right] + N_T \times L  \log \left(2\pi\right)   \\ \nonumber +\mathrm{tr}\left( \mathbf{C}_{\xi}^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma} \right) + (\mathbf{m})^\top \mathbf{C}_{\xi}^{-1} (\mathbf{m}) - \log \frac{|\mathbf{C}_{\xi}|}{|\mathbf{\Sigma}|} - K \Bigg) $$
The task:
$$ [\hat{\mathbf{m}}, \hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}}, \hat{\xi}] = \arg\max_{[{\mathbf{m}}, {\mathbf{\Sigma}}, \xi]} \mathrm{ELBO}({\mathbf{m}}, {\mathbf{\Sigma}}, \xi) $$
The first term in the parentheses of ELBO is an expected value but for the approximate distribution $q(\theta)$. Now, I am evaluating it with a Monte Carlo simulation, which is very time-consuming. Here, $\mathrm{vec}$ is the vectorized form of $\mathbf{Z}$, which is originally in 2D. The covariance $\mathbf{C}$ is a block diagonal matrix, and it is a function of $\theta$. The $q(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$. There are six parameters that control $\mathbf{C}_{\xi}$. The size of parameters $\theta$ is the same as $\mathbf{m}$, which is $3 \times K$. For $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, I use a diagonal matrix with $\mathrm{diag}[\mathbf{\Sigma}] = \mathbf{m}/N$, where $N$ is a constant to be estimated. If $K = 64$, the number of parameters to estimate is $6 + 192 + 1 = 199$. To estimate so many parameters, I can not afford so much computation time for the goal function to be evaluated once (because it involves the monte carlo expectation step). Are there ways to speed up the process?
I am using MATLAB. I use straightforward functions in MATLAB for all the evaluations. Even if I use the effective ones like $A\setminus B$ instead of $A*inv(B)$, it still takes a lot of time as it has to perform the Monte Carlo. In each Monte Carlo step, I need to sample $\theta$ as: $\theta \sim q(\theta)$. Any help is highly appreciated.

Just to confirm, $\theta$ is distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, correct? If so, then how is $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf Z)$ distributed?

Yes, correct; the variational distribution for $\theta$ is $q$ which is distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{\Sigma}) $. The $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})$ are the measurements and $\mathbf{C}$ is a parametric covariance of that measurements with  parameters $\theta$. I wanted to model $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})$as a Gaussian process of which the hyperparameters $\theta$ are also a Gaussian process with hyperparameters $\xi$ and i wanted to directly estimate $\xi$. As $\log p(\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})|\xi) $ is intractable, I derived the ELBO with a variational distribution for $\theta$.

Since $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf Z) \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, \mathbf{C})$, then couldn't you express $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf Z)$ as $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf Z) = \mathbf{C}^{1/2}v + \theta$, where $v \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf 0, \mathbf I)$ follows a multivariate standard normal distribution? This should allow you to express $$\mathbb{E}_{q(\theta)} \left[ \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{C}^{-1} \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z})\right]$$ directly as a function of $\theta$, thereby allowing you to obtain a closed-form expression, and no longer needing the monte-carlo approximation.

It is $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Z}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{C}(\theta))$ ; one example of $\mathbf{C}(\theta; t_a, t_b)$ is: $\exp(-2\pi^2 \theta_{(1)}^2 (t_a - t_b)^2) \cos(2\pi (t_a - t_b) \theta_{(2)} ) $, where $t_k$ are the times when thee measurements are recorded. And $\theta$ is comprised of two parameters $\theta = [\theta_{(1)} \theta_{(2)} ]$ this is on example. It can have more components. So, not so straightforward.
